# Missing Menu Links generating a Feature

Tags: features

I am using Features that includes several basic site features such as the main menu and another custom navigation menu. Both are two level menus.  I have included the menus in the Feature, but when I select the menu links, only a few of the menu link items are included in the selection list.  The balance are missing.

What I have done:

- I have searched for other issues on Drupal.org, but not found a similar one.
- I have also examined the links and cannot find a difference between those that are included and those that are not.
- I have flushed the menu cache.

Has anyone else seen anything like this or have any insights as to how I might fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be an issue that can be fixed by [UUIDs for Menu Links](https://www.drupal.org/project/uuid_features/issues/1283742), opened for the [UUID Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/uuid_features) Integration module. In that issue, one of the project maintainers suggested the feature should instead be implemented in a separated project. [UUID Features - Menu](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/ioskevich/2163429), a sandbox project, has been then created by [ioskevich](https://www.drupal.org/u/ioskevich).

Something to be aware of: Menu links don't show up in the administrative UI, nor get added to the database, if they are not for  existing nodes.

Comment: Thanks This link sounds correct.  The additional menu items all shared the 'node/add' as there link while I am building views to accommodate the actual menu targets.

Answer (score 0):

For future visitors, another possibility I found is link role filtering.  I was trying to feature the User-menu | Log in menu-item which is filtered to only display for anonymous users.  I verified there were no duplicates and tried uuid-menu-feature patch and it still would not show as an export option.  However, once I disabled the anonymous role filtering it showed up.